# Why detaching ChangeDetectorRef while calling detectChanges in ngOnChanges?

Tags: angular

I came across a component snippet that goes as follows:

```js
class FooComponent {
  cdr = inject(ChangeDetectorRef);

  constructor() {
    this.cdr.detach();
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    requestAnimationFrame(() => this.rendered());
    this.seed++; // force render subcomponent
  }
}
```

In the corresponding HTML template, the seed is passed to a subcomponent.

Under which circumstances is this useful? Why could the author have detached the change detection, but then trigger it manually again on every call of `ngOnChanges`, doesn't make this the optimization obsolete? Any insights what might have happened here is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

May be requestAnimationFrame(() => this.rendered()); take time and the dev do not want the angular to detect changes until the rendering is done.

and the seed++ is to force the child component to detect changes from the rendered frame

Comment: Also you could disable ZoneJs for all __Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame by putting this into polyfills.ts

(window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true;